# probability of rolling a sum of $14$ when rolling a $20$-sided die twice or a $20$-sided die with a $4$-sided die depending on outcome of first roll

Tags: probability

A $20$-sided die is rolled. If the result is $10$ or less, the $20$-sided die is rolled again. If the result is $11$ or more, a $4$-sided die is rolled. In either case, the results are summed after the second die roll. What is the probability that the sum will be $14$?

My Approach:
there are 10 ways we can get a sum of 14 if the first dice is  $<= 10$ {$(10,4),(9,5),(8,6),(7,7),(6,8),(5,9),(4,10),(3,11),(2,12),(1,13)$} and $3$ ways we can get sum of $14$ if the first dice has value  $>= 11$ {$(11,3),(12,2),(13,1)$} so the probability is: $(10/400)$ + $(3/80) = 1/16$

Comment: What goes wrong when you just write it out in the obvious way?

Comment: welcome to MSE. kindly include any attempt.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

$Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)Pr(B\mid A)$

$Pr(B) = Pr(A_1\cap B)+Pr(A_2\cap B)+\dots+Pr(A_n\cap B)$ where $A_1,\dots,A_n$ form a partition of the sample space

---

Let $B$ be the event the sum is $14$.

Let $A_1$ be the event the first die rolls a number $1-10$.  Let $A_2$ be the event the first die rolls a number $11-13$.  Let $A_3$ be the event the first die rolls a number $14+$.

**Additional Hint:**

> Regardless what was rolled on the first die, so long as it was less than $14$, there will be exactly one outcome on the second roll that would let the total sum to $14$.

Comment: I've added my approach. Not sure if it's correct.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{20}+\frac{3}{20}\times\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{16}$ is correct.  There is absolutely no need to write out each of the possibilities however and this causes errors when trying to count things by hand and wastes effort and time.

Answer (score -1):

The probability that you obtain $14$ using the $20$-sided die on the second role is

$$\frac{10}{20} \cdot \frac{1}{20}$$

The probability you obtain $14$ using the $4$-sided die on the second role is

$$\frac{3}{20} \cdot \frac{1}{4}$$

Add these.